# test case hangs on wrong validation

Tags: angular6, angular-test

I hope everyone in `SO` is doing well and keeping safe.

I am experiencing a strange behaviour. The `html` of my application should have an element with `id` `#submitted-answer-button`.

I am extracting the element and checking it like this (among other things)

```
const editButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#edit-practice-question-button'));
    const createAnswerButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#answer-question-button'));
    const submittedAnswerButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#submitted-answer-button'));
    const deleteButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#delete-practice-question-button'));

    console.log('checking if buttons exist 1', editButton);
    expect(editButton).toBeTruthy();
    console.log('checking if buttons exist 2',deleteButton);
    expect(deleteButton).toBeTruthy();
    console.log('checking if buttons exist 3',submittedAnswerButton);
    expect(submittedAnswerButton).toBeTruthy();
    console.log('checking if buttons exist 4');
    expect(createAnswerButton).toBeFalsy();
```

Interestingly, if I incorrectly code that `submittedAnswerButton` should be `falsy` then the test case hangs!!

const editButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#edit-practice-question-button'));
    const createAnswerButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#answer-question-button'));
    const submittedAnswerButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#submitted-answer-button'));
    const deleteButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#delete-practice-question-button'));

```
console.log('checking if buttons exist 1', editButton);
expect(editButton).toBeTruthy();
console.log('checking if buttons exist 2',deleteButton);
expect(deleteButton).toBeTruthy();
console.log('checking if buttons exist 3',submittedAnswerButton);
expect(submittedAnswerButton).toBeFalsy(); //THIS HANGS THE TEST RUN!
console.log('checking if buttons exist 4');
expect(createAnswerButton).toBeFalsy();
```

The `html` of the `component` is

```
<div [hidden]= "(this.tabType != this.questionTab)" id="form-div-question">
  <app-question-form [readonlyFormStatus]="!this.isEditing" (questionEmitter)="this.handleQuestionEmitEvent($event)" #questionForm ></app-question-form>
  <button *ngIf="!this.isEditing && this.isCreator"  type="button" id="edit-practice-question-button" class="unselected-button" (click)="this.editQuestion()"> Edit </button>
  <button *ngIf="!this.isEditing && this.isCreator"  type="button" id="delete-practice-question-button" class="unselected-button" (click)="this.deleteQuestion()"> Delete </button>
  <button *ngIf="(!this.isEditing) && (this.submitted_answer.answer.length !== 0)"  type="button" id="submitted-answer-button" class="unselected-button" (click)="this.showLoggedInUserSubmittedAnswerToTheQuestion()"> Your Submitted answer </button>
  <button *ngIf="(!this.isEditing) && (this.submitted_answer.answer.length === 0)"  type="button" id="answer-question-button" class="unselected-button" (click)="this.showAnswerTabAsUserWantsToAnswerQuestion()"> Create your Answer </button>

</div>

<div [hidden]="!(this.tabType == this.answerTab)" id="form-div-answer">
  <app-answer-form [submittedAnswer]="this.submitted_answer" #answerComponent (answerEmitter)="this.handleAnswerSubmission($event)" [questionId]="this.question_id"></app-answer-form>
</div>
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that the problem was due to the code `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#answer-question-button'));` which was behaving weirdly because my `html` had multiple elements with same `id`. I refactored the code so that each element has unique `id` and it seems the issue is resolved now.